# Go to Other Page When Form Input Element Is Clicked

Tags: html

So I wanted to make a form of login to a website and this is my code.

```html
<form method="post" class="form">
  <label for="user-email" style="padding-top:13px">&nbsp;Email</label>
   <input class="form-content" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" required/>
  <div class="form-border"></div>
  <label for="user-password" style="padding-top:22px">&nbsp;Password</label>
    <input class="form-content" type="password" name="password" required />
  <div class="form-border"></div>
    <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" />
</form>
```

But I cant figure out how to go to other page when I click the Login input. I tried to add `href=""`, but  it didnt work because its not an `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `action="yourPage.html"` in your form div.

```html
<form method="post" class="form" action="yourPage.html">
  <label for="user-email" style="padding-top:13px">&nbsp;Email</label>
   <input class="form-content" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" required/>
  <div class="form-border"></div>
  <label for="user-password" style="padding-top:22px">&nbsp;Password</label>
    <input class="form-content" type="password" name="password" required />
  <div class="form-border"></div>
    <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" />
</form>
```